# How to display multiple checkboxes both horizontally and vertically css

Tags: html, css, checkbox, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to set a collection of checkboxes both horizontally and vertically, but they don't come out uniformally.
The labels for each checkbox can vary in size, e.g. one label for a checkbox says "International Casaulty Treaty" whereas another only says WIP.

I was going over this vertical example here.
http://jsfiddle.net/zcuLgbxt/

How to can I neatly arrange them so they are all in alignment both vertically and horizontally?
Thanks very much in advance!

Here is my simple HTML/CSS

```css
li {
    margin: 5px;
}

input {
    width: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.vertical-list {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li{
    list-style:none;
}

.horizontal-list{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<center>    
  <ul>        
      <li>
          <input type="checkbox" >
          <label  class="vertical-list"> label1  label1  label1</label>
          <input type="checkbox"  >
          <label class="horizontal-list" for="myid2">label2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input type="checkbox" >
          <label class="vertical-list" >label2label2label2</label>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <label class="horizontal-list" for="myid2">label2label2</label>

      </li>

      <li>
          <input type="checkbox"  >
          <label class="vertical-list" > label4  label4  label4</label>
          <input type="checkbox"  >
          <label class="horizontal-list" >label2</label>
      </li>
  </ul>
</center>
```

Comment: the checkboxes to the right or left

Comment: Oh, either way is fine. I just need to get them arranged neatly regardless of length of the text labels. #

Comment: Can you seperate it so each list item only contains a single input/label like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vq3r58f0/1/)?

Comment: I didn't really get what you are trying to achieve, but be aware that you can assign an id to only one element. I see 4 elements with id "myid2". Anyway if you could try to explain better what you want to achieve maybe we can help you

Comment: Thanks Blank. I cleaned up the code a bit. Removed the "myid2". I'd just like to have the checkboxes aligned both vertically and horizontally regardless the label length. Not seen any examples of both, only vertical or one horizontal for checkboxes.

Comment: you can use display:flex;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS-Tables**

```css
li {
  margin: 5px;
  display: table-row;
}

li * {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

input {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical-list {}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.horizontal-list {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label class="vertical-list"> label1  label1  label1</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label class="horizontal-list" for="myid2">label2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label class="vertical-list">label2label2label2</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label class="horizontal-list" for="myid2">label2label2</label>

  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label class="vertical-list"> label4  label4  label4</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label class="horizontal-list">label2</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Paulie. Looks great. Just what I needed. Sorry if I wasn't clear beforehand. Much appreciated!